# How to edit a function signature at the same time

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm using VScode as my IDE, IN my college we require to write our codes using TopDown Design.
like this example:

```
void sum(int a, int b);
int main()
{
    int a=2, int b=3;
    sum(a,b);
    return 0;
}
void sum(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d", a+b);
}
```

My problem is that a lot of time while editing my function at the "Down LVL" I also need to edit the signature for adding or removing arguments, is there add-in or some key bind in VScode that can edit both signatures at the same time while I only edit one of them?
[image: my problem]

Comment: In sublime-text 3 at down left corner, If you click on it, you see replace option for this, I think VSCode has same thing probably

Comment: VSC is not an IDE it is an editor with benefits

Comment: Just put the definition of sum BEFORE main, no need to write a separate declaration. What you write is **NOT** Top-Down Design, it is a coding style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place the cursor over the signature and press `CTRL + D` you can select all the signatures, one at a time, then you can change them all in one go.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `alt + left click` to add a cursor in visual studio code.